# Интеграция Django2 с vk_api

Tags: python, django, vkontakte-api

Суть вопроса:
1. Как реализовать доступ бота к моделям?
2. (Более общий вопрос) к какому модулю Django лучше привязать запуск бота, чтобы он всегда был запущен вместе с Django-сервером, но при этом не было запущено несколько копий бота? Например, если запускать его с входом на сайт, то при каждом входе на сайт будет запускаться копия бота, а этого мне хотелось бы избежать

Есть вот такой бот ВК (написан на основе https://github.com/python273/vk_api), который отвечает на команды в ЛС сообщества:

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

def start():
    print('Bot started.')

    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='mytoken')
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
    print('LongPoll-session started.')

    admin_id_list = [
        # список ID администраторов бота, которым доступно больше команд
        163494096,
    ]

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:

            # при получении команды "!pins" бот должен отправить список постов из БД django
            if event.text in ('!pins',):
                # вот тут проблема
                from models import Post

                posts = [post for post in Post.objects.all() if post.isPinned]
                texts = [post.caption + '\n\n' + post.content + '\n\n' + post.pubdate + '\n==========\n' for post in posts]
                text = '\n\n'.join(texts)

                vk.messages.send (user_id = event.user_id, random_id = get_random_id(), message = text)

            # при получении команды "!pin заголовок | текст" должен создавать новый экземпляр модели с указанным заголовком и текстом
            elif event.text[:4] == '!pin':
                if event.user_id in admin_id_list:
                    # и тут тоже проблема :D
                    from models import Post
                    if len(event.text[5:].split('|', 1)) < 2:
                        post = Post(isPinned = True, caption = '', content = event.text[5:].strip(), pubdate = event.timestamp, isSended = False)
                        post.save()
                    else:   
                        post = Post(isPinned = True, caption = event.text[5:].split('|', 1)[0].strip(), content = event.text[5:].split('|', 1)[1].strip(), pubdate = event.timestamp, isSended = False)
                        post.save()
                else:
                    err_text = 'Ошибка: у вас недостаточно прав для закрепления сообщения.'
                    text = 'Пользователь ' + str(event.user_id) + ' попытался закрепить сообщение:\n\n' + str(event.text[5:]) + '\n\nЗапрос был отклонён: у пользователя недостаточно прав для закрепления сообщения.'
                    vk.messages.send (user_id = event.user_id, random_id = get_random_id(), message = err_text)
                    vk.messages.send (user_id = admin_id_list[0], random_id = get_random_id(), message = text)
            else:
                vk.messages.send (user_id = event.user_id, random_id = get_random_id(), message = 'Команда не распознана.')
        else:
            print('Non-command message recieved!')
```

Собственно, `models.py`, с которым работаем:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, date

class Post(models.Model):
    isPinned = models.BooleanField('Важное сообщение')
    caption = models.CharField('Заголовок сообщения', max_length = 100, blank = True)
    content = models.TextField('Текст сообщения')
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания сообщения')
    isSended = models.BooleanField('Отправлено ли сообщение')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Сообщение'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Сообщения'
```

Возникающая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 75, in <module>
    start()
  File "bot.py", line 43, in start
    from models import Post
  File "/home/e51675/public_html/main357/vk_integration/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Post(models.Model):
  File "/home/e51675/virtualenv/public_html/main357/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/e51675/virtualenv/public_html/main357/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/e51675/virtualenv/public_html/main357/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/e51675/virtualenv/public_html/main357/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/e51675/virtualenv/public_html/main357/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Если требуются уточнения по вопросу - пишите в комментариях, буду дополнять вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете инициализировать бота в файле `__init__.py`, который находится по соседству с настройками Вашего проекта.

Код из него будет однократно исполнен для инициализации пакета, поэтому он как нельзя кстати подходит для Ваших целей.

Но чтобы не засорять данный файл, принято добавлять в него только инструкции импорта, а необходимый для запуска код выносить в отдельный модуль.

***Пример:***

```py
# vk.py
from django.conf import settings
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api import VkUpload


vkSession = VkApi(token=settings.VK_ACCESS_TOKEN)
vk = vkSession.get_api()
vk_upload = VkUpload(vk)
```

```py
# __init__.py
from .vk import vk as vk_method, vk_upload


__all__ = ('vk_method', 'vk_upload')
```

Для обработки событий стоит использовать `Callback API`, вместо `longPoll`.
Вот как может выглядеть представление для получения событий:

```py
# views.py — модуль в приложении
from django.conf import settings
from django.views import View
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json


# Create your views here.
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class VkHookView(View):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        d = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

        if d['secret'] == settings.VK_HOOK_SECRET and d['group_id'] == int(settings.VK_GROUP_ID):
            if d['type'] == 'message_new':
                obj = d['object']
                message = obj['message']

                # Write Your code here

            elif d['type'] == 'confirmation':
                return HttpResponse(settings.VK_CONFIRMATION_CODE)

        return HttpResponse('ok')
```

---

Возвращаясь обратно к вопросу о запуске кода, стоит сказать об ещё одном способе.

Часто бывает, что инициализировать что-то нужно только для конкретного приложения. В таком случае, рекомендуется использовать метод `ready` класса соответствующего приложения в `apps.py`.

***Пример:***

```py
# apps.py — модуль в приложении
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ApplicationConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'application'

    def ready(self):
        import application.scripts  # Модуль, который необходимо запустить
```

Comment: @Евгений Файл с функциями обработки `longPoll` можно поместить куда угодно, но от этого будет зависеть способ запуска. Если Вы помещаете его по соседству с `settings.py`, то запускаете с помощью импорта в `__init__.py`, если отдельным модулем в приложение, то желательно запускать с помощью импорта в методе `ready` класса соответствующего приложения. В обоих случаях стоит следить, чтобы ничего не зациклилось. Я обновил ответ, добавив ещё один пример запуска.

Comment: @Евгений Кстати, обратите, пожалуйста, внимание на соседний ответ. Использование `Callback API` является гораздо лучшим подходом и сразу решает ряд проблем. При использовании `Callback API` Вам не нужно будет думать о том, чтобы запускать обработку событий отдельным потоком/процессом и следить за её работоспособностью. Вы должны будете лишь инициализировать класс бота (`VkApi`), а затем написать представление, остальное сделает Ваш сервер и `Django`. Если Вы решите использовать `Callback API`, то я могу привести пример представления для его обработки.

Comment: Если приведёте пример решения с `Callback API` - буду благодарен. К сожалению, раньше не имел опыта интеграции API с Django, потому примера из официальной документации мне недостаточно =/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102832/discussion-between-nomnoms12-and-).

Comment: Обновите, пожалуйста, ответ с решением, представленным в вашем репозитории, и я отмечу его, как правильный. Спасибо за помощь =)

Comment: @Евгений Готово. Убрал немного воды, добавил ссылку [на GitHub](https://github.com/nomnoms12/scripts/tree/master/django_vk_callback_api_example/project) и представление из репозитория. Если есть предложения по улучшению, предлагайте :)

Answer (score 2):

У вк есть [CallBack API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), django сервер может выступать как сервер с ответами на эти запросы. Там же есть пример реализации, как раз с вашим требованием

Comment: Это отличный подход. Но увы, в официальной документации нет примеров на `Python` и на `Django` в частности.

Comment: @nomnoms12 там пример на php, а это бэкэнд сервера, почти то же что и Django